# When you use Clear All in Excel, what default font does Excel fall back on and how to change this font?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my case this font is Arial, but why Arial and how can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this by changing the font of one cell from my default of Calibri to Arial. I then used clear all on that cell and it reverted to Calibri.

When I look in File>Options>General, I see that the value for "Use this as the default font" is "Body Font".

[image]

I also see that the default body font for my Office theme is "Calibri":

[image]

So. I think you have two options:

1. Change the value in the default font for new workbooks drop-down as displayed above
2. Change your office theme and use "Body Font" or "Headings Font" as the default for new workbooks

Comment: In "Use this as the default font" I have Arial Narrow and I want to keep it after Clear All is applied. I also have Arial Narrow in the Excel template files, so every new file and new sheet has Arial Narrow as the default. When I changed "Use this as the default font" to Body Font, I still get Arial after Clear All. I am not sure about what you mean in #1. As to #2, how do I change office theme in Excel? (In Word I have Calibri as default).

Comment: FlexYourData: Even before I saw the OP’s comment, I was thinking that this would be a better answer if it described how to change themes.  I’ve been using Excel for over ten years and I didn’t know how to do it.  (Also, it would be a better answer if you had done the research and determined whether changing the default font to use *when creating new workbooks* would address the OP’s question about “Clear All”.)